# Insert 0 values into a Prometheus Query

Tags: prometheus

My task is to get some kind of "grafana-agent" monitoring, basically get an alert if a "$host" doesn't push metrics to Prometheus (alerting is set up on Grafana)
My query as of now is:
`(up{cluster_environment=~"dev|sit|acc", job="integrations/agent"} offset 5m) unless up{cluster_environment=~"dev|sit|acc", job="integrations/agent"}`

If I stop "grafana-agent", after few minutes I can see that the query starts to show value "1" and it goes through the offset, but after 5 minutes the alert resolves itself, because the query doesn't look more than that offset. I could do it for 1hour, but I can't seem to get up the alerting thing right:
My problem is that setting up an alert on Grafana always show the latest value of "1" and if grafana-agent is working, it doesn't push "0" or any other value. Basically it's non-data and the alerting can't work that way.
How would it be possible to send "0" as a value if no-data is received or make it more logical, that if query results 1, that's an alert and if it's "0" it resolves? ( maybe offset is not needed here at all?)

Tried combining query with vector(0), but then I lose my labels and it adds an additional "series" which I don't need ant I can't combine them both.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus has [absent function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#absent) for this use case. Try:

```
absent(up{cluster_environment=~"dev|sit|acc", job="integrations/agent"})
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for input, but it seems that after I start the grafana-agent, the query no longer sends any value and the last value was "1" when the grafana-agent was offline.  
Also, how I should make this query as a unified alert because after it's down I can only search if i specifically describe the node node="test1", otherwise the query doesn't find anything

Comment: This answer requires explanation. How `absent` supposed to help? How it supposed to be used (use it instead of current query or add to it, if latter - how)? Do you aware of behaviour of absent in the following `absent(up{instance=~"http://localhost:9100|non-existent"})`, and how it will affect alert?

Comment: Also, `absent(up{labelname="nonexistent"})` will produce `{labelname="nonexistent"} 1`, but `absent(up{labelname=~"nonexistent"})` will produce `{} 1`, because `absent` is not clever enough to work around regexes.